# How to use a cell value to define the sheet on IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange

Trying to create a spreadsheet that reads values from a certain sheet of another file using `importrange` formula.
I am trying that the referenced external cell be a cell on the current one so I could try to do something like:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXX";**E2**&"!G3"))
```

E2 local cell is the name of the remote sheet I want to import from.

[This reply](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92998/using-cell-value-to-define-sheet-reference-e-g-a1b2) looked very promising using the `INDIRECT` formula but so far I haven't managed to archive it within an `importrange` not sure if due to a syntax error or a limitation of the `importrange`:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXX";INDIRECT(E2&"!G3"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`IMPORTRANGE`** is like a smaller sister of **`INDIRECT`** so you are not supposed to have **`INDIRECT`** in **`IMPORTRANGE`**, so all you need to do is to allow access and:

[image: 0]

```
=IMPORTRANGE("16nnuzNRx_kGGJm1EBVX7kBT2bfW1-2TYwSiuaLF-QI"; E2&"!G3")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I would have bet I did already tried that directly but probably with wrong syntax. It works, thanks.